# Is it possible to require external storage on an Android Device

Tags: android, storage

Is it possible to stop devices without external storage seeing an applicaiton on the Play Store?

I don;t mean manually by excluding those devices fro the Play Dev UI. I mean using the manifest. I suspect not but I;d love somebody to tell me otherwise.

Comment: You are right, manifest doesn't have tag for this functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, you can only limit by the features listed [here in this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference).

The best/only option might be to check [if external storage is available](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) and provide messaging to the user if it isn't. If your app requires external storage you may want to do this anyway, as Google puts it: "The media might be mounted to a computer, missing, read-only, or in some other state."

Imagine a user temporarily removed their sd card, or plugs their phone into a computer...I think it's fair that you wouldn't expect Google Play to hide/show apps depending on the current external storage state.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'm already checking for the mount state of external storage. I was just hoping I could stop people without external storage from installing it in the first place. Cheers

Comment: Hi Panda, what did you end up doing if you don't mind me asking :) I am going through the same and am leaning towards notifying the user via a message that External Storage is required.